# Type check in SCSS?

Tags: css, sass

Basically I am attempting to set a CSS value based on whether a value passed into an SCSS mixin is even or odd.

Done some looking around and have found diddly squat. Any mention of odd / even in a search term with CSS/SCSS just results in :nth-child results.

Remainder operator doesn't work in CSS so that method of determining an odd / even number wont work. I then attempted to go down the route where a number divided by 2 would result in either a number type or integer type depending if it was even or odd, nope.

My only feasible option seems to be

```
$valType1: "odd";

   @if $val1 == 2 {
    $valType1: "even";
  } @else if $val1 == 4 {
    $valType1: "even";
  } @else if $val1 == 6 {
    $valType1: "even";
  } @else if $val1 == 8 {
    $valType1: "even";
  } @else if $val1 == 10 {
    $valType1: "even";
  } @else if $val1 == 12 {
    $valType1: "even";
  } @else if $val1 == 14 {
    $valType1: "even";
  } @else if $val1 == 16 {
    $valType1: "even";
  } @else if $val1 == 18 {
    $valType1: "even";
  } @else if $val1 == 20 {
    $valType1: "even";
  } @else if $val1 == 22 {
    $valType1: "even";
  } @else if $val1 == 24 {
    $valType1: "even";
  } @else if $val1 == 26 {
    $valType1: "even";
  }

  @if $valType1 == "even" {
    background-color: red;
  }
```

There's gotta be something. Any help suggestions? Am I overlooking something painfully obvious?

Comment: Where does `$val1` come from? Is it something that can change at run-time or is it only available to the SCSS preprocessor?

Comment: It is an arbitrary variable that is defined in the mixin.

```@mixin mixin-name($val1, $val2) {  code }```

it is then called

```@include mixin-name(23, 34)```

Comment: So, if it is never exposed to CSS then you don't need to worry about "Remainder operator doesn't work in CSS". Just use the % operator in SCSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good use of `@function` instead of a mixin. And you can use the `%` [modulo operator](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/modulo-operator-in-c-cpp-with-examples/) for this.

Added a `@mixin` for clarity (and another option).

```css
@function evenOdd( $value) {
    $number : blue;
    
    @if ($value % 2 == 0) {
        $number : red 
    }
    
    @return $number;
}

@mixin evenOdd( $value ) {
    @if ($value % 2 == 0) {
        background-color: red;
    } @else {
        background-color: blue;
    }
}

.selector {
    background-color: evenOdd(2);
    /* compiles to red */
}

.selector {
    background-color: evenOdd(3);
    /* compiles to blue */
}

.selector {
    background-color: evenOdd(4);
    /* compiles to red */
}

/* MIXINS */
.selector {
    @include evenOdd(2);
    /* compiles to background-color: red */
}

.selector {
    @include evenOdd(3);
    /* compiles to background-color: blue */
}
```

You can past this into https://www.sassmeister.com/ - and watch the magic happen.

Answer (score 1):

Sass supports numeric operators, so you could use modulo to calculate the parity of your value.

```scss
$valType1: "odd";

@if $val1 % 2 == 0 {
    $valType1: "even";
}

@if $valType1 == "even" {
    background-color: red;
}
```